# getting the content of an invalid Xml Document in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk

I have a Biztalk orchestration that posts to a http site. the response that comes back is of xmlDocument type, but it only contains a 0, no html/xml at all. All I want to do is set that 0 to a string or something to output it, but I cannot use any of the xmldocument functions because the xml is not well formed, and I cant use maps because there is no schema to work with. Trying to use any xml function returns an "invalid root level" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string variable and use Xpath to set the value from the response message in an Expression Shape.

You can use a XMLDocument Message and create it in an Assign Shape. You can assign the string variable to an element in the message.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at using a Pipeline Component to wrap the response - e.g. have a look at the Flat File samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee277286%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx)